# Characteristic base curves

Tags: initial-value-problems

$$u u_x + (y + 1) u_y = u , x ∈ R, y > 0$$
$$u(x,0)=-3x,  x ∈ R $$

I found the solution of the above initial value problem to be $$u(x,y)=  \frac{-3x(y+1)}{(-3y+1)} $$

If someone could confirm this it would be fantastic.
How do I sketch the characteristic base curves and define the region where the
solution can be determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic base curves are the straight lines $x = s(1−3y)$. Where these lines intersect at the point$ (0, 1/3) $ .